# Solaris: Find files matching a pattern but only display the directory name

Tags: find

Like it says above. I'm trying to find a simple way to look for a pattern in a file name and display only the directory in which it is found.

For example, given a tree structure that looks like this:

```
./projecta
./projecta/src/code1.p
./projecta/src/code2.p
./projecta/util.p
./projectb
```

I would want the command "whatever *.p" to return:

```
./projecta/src
./projecta
```

Hope that makes sense. Any further info, please signify in the usual manner.

TIA

N/

Comment: Can this be done through a shell? Or does it need to be done programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the directories of `.c` files:

```
find . -name \*.c -exec dirname {} \; | uniq
```

To display the directories of `.html` files:

```
find . -name \*.html -exec dirname {} \; | uniq
```

If you want to use that in a script,

```
#/bin/bash

ext=$1
find . -name \*.${ext} -exec dirname {} \; | uniq
```

Comment: dirname damnit! I always think of basename and always forget dirname. Thanks muchly.